# How do I make sure text doesn't move?

Tags: text, lua, coronasdk

There is probably a very simple solution for this:
I have this text object:

```
pointDisp = display.newText("Score: "..score, 30, 20, native.systemFont, 30)
```

Occasionally, I change the text. Sometimes score is 0, sometimes score is 10000. I would like the text to expand to the right and always start at x-position 30, but when the text includes a lot of characters, the text expands and moves outwards in both directions (even though the x-position for the object remains 30).
Can anyone help?

Comment: Added `corona` tag because, I guess you use it. If you don't sorry for edit and revert it.

Comment: What library/module/etc is your `display.newText` coming from? I tried searching the standard docs, but I can't seem to be able to find it, and I don't think its part of the standard Lua.

Comment: By the way: Lua is not an acronym so you should not capitalize all the letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Corona documentation page for the `display.newText()` function:

> Creates a text object with its top-left corner at (left, top).

More specifically, down in the 'gotcha's' section:

> Currently, there is no way to align text upon creation. It is recommended you create the text, then set the reference point using [object:setReferencePoint()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/setReferencePoint.html), and adjust the x and y coordinates accordingly.

This spells out pretty clearly what you need to do to get your desired results.

Comment: Perfect! I had read through it twice but missed the gotcha part. Thanks!